# Eclipse 4.4 Luna: Editor window, "Show List" drop-down alternative text

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna, eclipse-mars

I just swapped to eclipse Luna (4.4.1) from a previous version and I have a little problem I cant solve.

I don't know why but the class filter in editor window doesn't show the package name of the class you are hovering with the mouse (the alt text). It worked fine in previous versions of eclipse but I cant find any related in preferences.

I dont know if this is the acourate name for this part of the IDE so I show you a pic of what I'm trying to say. **EDIT:** This is the "Show List" drop-down

**EDIT 2:** Also happens on eclipse mars (4.5) with a new workspace.

[Cant upload images yet](https://imageshack.com/i/p1vypRORj)

Tranks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any image on your image link

Comment: Try this [http://i.imgur.com/L0np9tV.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/L0np9tV.jpg)